# How to write a wrapper script in unix that calls other shell scripts sequentially?

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a wrapper script that calls other shell scripts in a sequential manner

There are 3 shell scripts that pick .csv files of a particular pattern from a specified location and process them.
I need to run them sequentially by calling them from one wrapper script

Let's consider 3 scripts 
a.ksh, b.ksh and c.ksh that run sequentially in the same order.

The requirement is that the script should fail if a.ksh fails but continue if b.sh fails.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can find out the return code of any command/script using `if [ $? -eq 0 ] ;then echo passed;else echo faile ;fi` . You can fit your a/b/c scripts into similar if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
./a.ksh && ./b.ksh; ./c.ksh
```

I haven't tried this out. Do test with sample scripts that fail/pass before using.

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists